# TWRP Recovery installation not working

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp

I am following these instructions to root my Galaxy Light - http://rootmygalaxy.net/root-galaxy-light-sgh-t399-install-twrp-recovery/. Part 1 seemed to work fine, but I am not able to boot into TWRP recovery with Vol Up + Power + Home, it's still the regular recovery mode with the volume up and down buttons to select options. How can I get to the TWRP recovery mode? I have a locked bootloader.

Odin Message:

```
<ID:0/006> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> openrecovery-twrp-2.8.4.0-gardalte.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/006> Odin v.3 engine (ID:6)..
<ID:0/006> File analysis..
<ID:0/006> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/006> Initialzation..
<ID:0/006> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/006> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/006> recovery.img
<ID:0/006> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/006> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/006> RES OK !!
<ID:0/006> Removed!!
<ID:0/006> Remain Port ....  0 
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 1 / failed 0)
```

Comment: Also, turn off the Auto-Reboot option in Odin settings (if applicable). Let the device power off after the flash and reboot it to recovery directly.  I read it somewhere that the auto-reboot option will trigger a reboot of the Android system, which might over write the recovery with one from a backup partition.

Answer (score 1):

I noted from the provided link that your device is a Samsung Light SGH-T399, running Android Jellybean 4.2.2.

With that considered, you can try the [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276) app to root your device. Follow the steps below (guide in the link) to root the device. After rooting the device, copy the TWRP image to your internal SD card from your computer, and use the Flashify app (get it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2349847) or [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify)) to flash it to your recovery partition. Again, the app itself will be pretty clear as to what you need to do, or follow the steps below.

## Framaroot usage (from the XDA link <sub>(with corrections and emphasis)</sub>):

> ## Installation:
>
> 1. Download it to your device (links are available at the end of the linked XDA post)
> 2. Install it with a file explorer or directly from your internet browser, if android warn you about security risk, say OK and check Unknown sources to allow install of applications outside of Play Store.
>
> ## Usage:
>
> Open Framaroot and select one of the following actions:
>
> 1. Install SuperSU
> 2. Unroot
> 3. Execute script (for advanced users)
>
> ## Possible cases once application has been launched:
>
> A popup saying "Your device seems not vulnerable to exploit included in Framaroot", in this case you can uninstall app
>   You seeing one or more exploit name, also click on one after you have selected an action and you will see one of the above messages
>
> ## Possible cases once exploit had been selected:
>
> 1. "Success  ... Superuser and su binary installed. You have to reboot your device"
> 2. "Failed  ... Exploit work but installation of Superuser and su binary have failed"
> 3. "Half-Success :-/ ... system partition is read-only, use local.prop trick. Reboot your device and use adb to see if it run as root", happen when the filesystem in use on system partition is a read only filesystem (ex: squashfs)
> 4. "Failed  ... Try another exploit if available"
> 5. Framaroot crashed or foze, in this case relaunch Framaroot a second time and select the same action and exploit.

## Flashify usage:

- Refer below screenshot. Tap on the "Recovery Image" button.
- Select the recovery image file you had copied to your decice earlier.
- Accept the confirmation dialog.
- You're done, reboot.

## Flashify flash screen:

<sub>(image credits @cgollner of XDA,the Flashify developer)</sub>

<sub>Click on image for larger version</sub>

[image: Flashify Flash Screen]

Reboot to recovery using `adb reboot recovery`, the Flashify app or the key combination, configure TWRP time zone and other stuff, take a NANDroid backup and then go do whatever you want with the device, flash ROMs and whatnot.

If you are worried that the custom recovery may get reset after a reboot, you need not. That particular issue is only applicable to flashes via ODIN on certain select enterprise-class devices (and most probably yours isn't one of them), and has nothing to do with the suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everybody. This morning, I downloaded Odin from a different place, tried to do the same thing, and booted into TWRP Recovery fine. I don't know what I did differently, but my phone is rooted now.

Comment: Maybe you turned off auto-reboot as Tamoghna Chowdhury mentioned -- it was enabled in your Odin screenshot.