# Download Mode in Galaxy Grand Prime

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-grand

Ok so I rooted my phone useing King root downloaded twrp, busy box pro. Anyway I went to reboot in bootloader and i got a downloading screen. How long should this take. Anyway I'm a noob to rooted phones so not positive what I did. I can send a pic of the screen if needed.

Comment: Please do post that pic, as well as your exact model number and Android version. That particular Samsung model AFAIK doesn't actually have any use for the bootloader for flashing partition images from a PC. *Try keeping the power button pressed until your phone reboots to Android normally.* The `Downloading` thing is the Samsung `Download Mode` for flashing firmware from a PC using ODIN,  it doesn't download anything from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

That `Downloading` screen you got is representative of having entered Samsung's special `Download Mode` for flashing device firmware from a PC over ODIN. Over there, *Downloading* means downloading from the PC, not from the internet. In case you want to get back to *normal* Android, keep holding down the <kbd>Power</kbd> button until the device reboots. For flashing TWRP, you can try using this app called [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify). For using it, refer to my other answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/138978/92056).